# Idiom "strike me peculiar"?

Tags: phrases, idioms

I've always used the phrasing

> It strikes me **as** peculiar that ....

But I've come across an example which reads

> It strikes me peculiar that ....

It could be a typo but this comes from a text which has been carefully checked for mistakes.

I wanted to find out from others if the second phrasing exists, albeit uncommon?

The meaning I derive from each is slightly different. The second I read as meaning, "it turns me into something peculiar", or "makes me feel strange"; whereas the first phrasing places the strangeness in the observed phenomena, not in the self.

Comment: It's just an informalism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction *strikes me [adj.]* instead of the standard *strikes me as [adj.]* may occur in informal spoken English in Britain, America, or Australia, including, apparently, a fictional talking horse. No difference in meaning results from omitting the *as*, and there appears to be only a limited set of adjectives employed in this construction, at least within earshot of a search engine.

> ’But what [*strikes me odd*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=%22strikes%20me%20odd%22;id=njp.32101066122530;view=image;seq=188;start=1;sz=10;page=root;num=176;size=100;orient=0),’ says she to me, ’is that all the harticles is marked with C, and not one with N.’ Now, sir,” continued Mrs. Brown, “I always goes a great deal by the under clothes, and that is a proof positer to me that they are something higher than they seems. You often see your flourishing would-be grandees, with a gown and bonnet on fit for a queen; and then if you could only catch a look at the shimmy, you would be surprised.” — Elizabeth Caroline Grey, *The Duke*, v. 2, London 1839.(Odd mix of quotation marks is original)
>
> “That [*strikes me queer*](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/101006264?searchTerm=%22strikes+me+queer%22),” replied the horse after a moment's thought.  “You can scarcely read or write, your grammar is way off, and your wife and child are ashamed of their clothes. …” *Nepean Times* (Penrith NSW), 6 July 1889.
>
> The sarcasm of the firm who cannot “Keep Cool” with a “Forty-seven Thousand Dollar Stock” on hand, and only $5000 to raise, [*strikes me funny*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=%22strikes%20me%20funny%22;id=nyp.33433090803275;view=image;seq=1253;start=1;sz=10;page=root;num=47;size=100;orient=0), and his readers as a fake. — *Boot and Shoe Recorder* v. 21, no. 22, Boston MA, 31 Aug. 1892.
>
> It [*strikes me peculiar*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=%22strikes%20me%20peculiar%22;id=coo.31924011733528;view=image;seq=108;start=1;sz=10;page=root;num=64;size=100;orient=0) that a town should pay $60.00 a year for a road and $287.00 for maintenance … — Proceedings, Sixth Annual Good Roads Convention of the Board of Supervisors of the State of New York, Albany, 24–25 Jan. 1905.
>
> … but what [*strikes me peculiar*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=%22strikes%20me%20peculiar%22;id=mdp.39015012688019;view=image;seq=97;start=1;sz=10;page=root;num=89;size=100;orient=0) in this discussion is that Mr. Walsh tells us he has had a stoker which has given good success, and which he has used for a couple of years. — Proceedings, Annual Convention of the American Railway Master Mechanics’ Association, v.41, 1908.
>
> What [*struck me peculiar*](https://books.google.de/books?id=3X8eAQAAMAAJ&q=%22struck+me+peculiar%22&dq=%22struck+me+peculiar%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr_cy02LbhAhWlPOwKHbEHAU0Q6AEIKTAB), too, were him keepin' that bit yacht lyin' out at moorin's, for he never seemed to use her; an' to me certain knowledge the only time she'd been out up till then were when I took her a trial trip. — *The Scots Magazine* 13 (1930), 356.
>
> It [*strikes me unusual*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=%22strikes%20me%20unusual%22;id=uc1.aa0000355149;view=image;seq=428;num=3548;start=1;sz=10;page=search), we get testimony as to the invulnerability of these satellites to really an awful lot of low power types of threats, and I am not trying to get into anything classified, but how is it that we have not been planning ahead in this area? — Sen. Jeff Bingaman (D-NM), Department of Defense Authorization, FY 1985, Senste Subcommittee on Strategic and Theater Nuclear Forces, 12 April 1984.
>
> “It [*strikes me bizarre*](http://warwickonline.com/stories/city-motel-6-draft-plan-to-stem-criminal-activity,101667?category_id=4&content_class=1&town_id=1&sub_type=stories) that they care so little about their customers’ privacy,” ACLU executive director Steven Brown said in a phone interview. — *Warwick Beacon* (RI), 16 Apr. 2015.

Comment: Oh.  I thought you had found a quote from Mr. Ed.